# displaying boxplot for some x variable with scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to display box plot for some x variable ,like here for duration 4 and 5 I have to display boxplot and overlay with scatterplot. Also I have to rename the x axis. I am using the below code.
The problem is the x axis is getting misaligned  like .11,12 is getting before 3,4.

```
ggplot(data=data_1,aes(x=DUR,y=val))+
  geom_boxplot(data=subset(data_1[,c("val","ID","DUR")],data_1$DUR %in% c(4,5)), aes(DUR,val))+
  geom_jitter(data=subset(data_1, !is.na(DUR)),aes(x=DUR,y=val),position=position_jitter(width=.1, height=0),alpha=0.5,size=4,color='grey')+
  labs(y = "val", x = "Duration",title='val data%')+
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = comparison_1, label.y =  c(56,57,59))+
  stat_compare_means(size=5,label.y = 50,method ="anova")+theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size=16,angle=0,vjust = 0.5),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.ticks=element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.border =  element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=0.5),panel.background = element_blank())+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  scale_x_discrete(name = 'DUR',breaks = c('3','4', '5', '6', '7', '9','11','12'), 
                   labels = c('Exp-3\nDur 6','Exp-4\nDur 7', 'Exp-5\nProcess 8', 'Exp-6\nDur 9', 'Exp-7\nDur 10', '9','11','12'))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = c('bold', 'bold', 'bold', 'bold', 'bold','plain', 'plain','plain'),size = c('11','11','11','11','11','9','9','9')))
```

[image]

Comment: Try running `data_1$DUR <-  as.numeric(as.character(data_1$DUR))` then retrying your plot code. Difficult to know what the problem is for sure without seeing your data.

Comment: i did it before running the  ggplot    ```data1$DUR<-as.numeric(as.character(data1$DUR))
data1$DUR<-as.factor(as.numeric(data1$DUR))``` . The problem is somewhere happening when I am using subset for boxplot and selecting days 4 and 5 while for scatter ,I am considering all the days

Comment: Please include a reproducible example so that we can help you more easily.

Comment: you can see the figure. I am using subset function to get days 4,5 in boxplot and am using all days in jitter but after plotting the  the x axis is getting misaligned. 11 and 12 days are showing before Exp3/Dur6. those 2 should be in the end after day 9.I have used factor to level the days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace `breaks` with `limits` in `scale_x_discrete`.  That should do it.  As an example, I have run it on `mtcars` below.  With `breaks`, you will get 11 before 4 on `x-axis`, as in your case.

```
  data1 <- mtcars %>% select(mpg, cyl, carb) %>% rename(val=mpg, ID=cyl, DUR=carb)
  data1$DURN <- data1$DUR + 3
  data_1 <- data1
  data_1$DUR <- as.character(data1$DURN)
  
  p <- ggplot(data=data_1,aes(x=DUR, y=val))+
    geom_boxplot(data=subset(data_1[,c("val","ID","DUR")],data_1$DUR %in% c(4,5)), aes(DUR,val))+
    geom_jitter(data=subset(data_1, !is.na(DUR)),aes(x=DUR,y=val),position=position_jitter(width=.1, height=0),alpha=0.5,size=4,color='grey')+
    labs(y = "mpg", x = "carb plus three",title='mpg data%')  +
    # stat_compare_means(comparisons = comparison_1, label.y =  c(56,57,59))+
    # stat_compare_means(size=5,label.y = 20,method ="anova") +
    theme(
      axis.text.x = element_text(size=12,angle=0,vjust = 0.5),
      panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks=element_line(colour = "black"),
      panel.border =  element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=0.5),
      panel.background = element_blank()) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    scale_x_discrete(name = 'DURATION', limits = c('4', '5', '6', '7', '9','11'),
                     labels = c('Exp-4\nDur 7', 'Exp-5\nProcess 8', 'Exp-6\nDur 9', 'Exp-7\nDur 10', '9','11')
                     )  +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = c( 'bold', 'bold', 'bold', 'bold','plain', 'plain'),size = c('11','11','11','11','9','9')))
```

**UPDATE:** Adding some custom annotations at the bottom in red color.

```
  ### create a dataframe to pass in textGrob
  xc <- c('4', '5', '6', '7', '9', '11')
  x_axis <- c(1:6)
  y_axis <- rep(10,6)
  dfx <- data.frame(xc, x_axis, y_axis)
  
  #Add annotations
  for (i in 1:length(unique(dfx$xc))){
    p <- p + annotation_custom(textGrob(label = paste0('n=',dfx$xc[i]),
                               # rot = 90,  ## if you wish to rotate
                               gp = gpar(fontsize = 10, col="red")),
      xmin = dfx$x_axis[i],
      xmax = dfx$x_axis[i],
      ymin = dfx$y_axis[i],
      ymax = dfx$y_axis[i]
    )
  }
  p
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks @YBS for the help. I have one more requirement, where I need to tick per day count on top of the graph. like for  EXP-4 there is n=7, EXp-5,n=9,Exp-6 n=3.These n values I need to put on top  for each x value.

Comment: Thanks @YBS. I thought of asking here as it was a continuation of the question. I just need to put the no of cells each day on top .I wasn't able to figure out how to add another scale_x_discrete function.